# memory does not contain garbage prior to variable assignment

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb

I have a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using gcc:

```
gcc -g test.c
```

Then I run the debugger:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
```

I set a breakpoint at main and run:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
```

I then let it run until it hits the breakpoint and try to display the assembly instruction at the address rip is currently pointing:

```
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x400538 <main+8>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
```

It looks like the next instruction is going to initialize my local variable i with the value 0. Since it hasn't executed the instruction yet, I'd expect a garbage value to be there.

```
(gdb) x/4xb $rbp-4
0x7fffffffe0ec: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

It doesn't look like garbage values, it looks like everything has already been zero'd out. The breakpoint should halt the program before any of the code in main is executed.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't that memory location contain random garbage values before the local variable i is initialized?

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: 00 is still a random value.

Comment: You never set the value you're referring to. Per the standard unless it has static linkage, it has indeterminate value prior to any initialization or assignment. Who are *you* to say 0x00 doesn't qualify as *indeterminate*? (I'm partial  to 0x33 myself, so 0x00 somewhat raises my hackles).

Answer (score 3):

> It doesn't look like garbage values, it looks like everything has already been zero'd out.

I modified your example in order to show that it is just a coincidence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
  int i4;
  int i5;
  int i6;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("Hello\n");

  return 0;
}
```

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ac: file main.cpp, line 13.
Starting program: /home/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:13
13        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
(gdb) info locals
i1 = 0
i3 = 0
i5 = 32767
i = 0
i2 = 4195520
i4 = -7856
i6 = 0
```

You see, different values are possible.

As for your example the value at this address changes at least twice before reaching `main()`. Just set `watch` for this address and you will see that it is changed in functions called before main():

```
(gdb) watch *(int*)0x7fffffffe06c
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(int*)0x7fffffffe06c

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a.out
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(int*)0x7fffffffe06c

Old value = 0
New value = 58
0x0000003a1d890880 in handle_intel () from /lib64/libc.so.6


Hardware watchpoint 1: *(int*)0x7fffffffe06c

Old value = 58
New value = 0
0x0000003a1d0146fd in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Hardware watchpoint 1: *(int*)0x7fffffffe06c

Old value = 0
New value = 1
0x00000000004005c3 in main () at main.cpp:7
7         for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
#0  0x00000000004005c3 in main () at main.cpp:7
```

Answer (score 2):

A garbage value might be anything, including the value 0. The contents of that local variable are undefined, until the point where it is assigned a value. You cannot expect the contents to be of a certain kind before that happens.

It is however quite common that a zero-out is done on all local variables during debug builds. If this is the case with gdb, I have no idea. You could try printing the contents of the variable before it is initialized, then make a release build with no debugger and see if the behavior is the same.

More likely though, the compiler made the decision to initialize the variable earlier than the actual line i=0. A compiler is free to change the order in which the program is executed, if it can determine that doing so won't affect the program results. The compiler might have moved the zero-out to an earlier point in the program for performance reasons.

Comment: I was hoping to find some concrete documentation on what you are suggesting, that a zero-out is done on all local variables during debug builds. This is a really old article for Windows programming, but it talks about how when you allocate memory in a debug build, it is initialized to a special value to try and help you catch errors:
http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1198/c/c1198.aspx

I know the value is undefined and should never be trusted, I just wanted to know for my own knowledge if any "special initialization" occurred in debug builds only to try and help catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what is meant by "garbage" (which is not even a formal term). Uninitialized objects in C have *indeterminate value*. This does not mean the value is random, much less that it has any value as entropy (there was actually a huge OpenSSL/Debian fiasco over this misunderstanding long before Heartbleed happened and everyone realized what a mess OpenSSL was). All it means is that you **cannot use the value**. If you do, you don't have a valid C program but a meaningless one, and there's no point in trying to reason about what it does (except possibly if you're an attacker trying to exploit a vulnerability in the program).

Comment: My understanding, and I could be wrong since I am a bit rusty, was that an uninitialized variable x should never be accessed until it is properly initialized. This is because memory location &x could contain anything. Trying to access the value would have undefined results, and might even crash your program. Maybe I am just overthinking things, but for some reason I find it mildly suspicious that the value 0 exists in all of these random memory locations before the variable is initialized. I was just wondering if local variables were auto initialized to 0 in debug builds to help catch errors.

Comment: Part of my reason for this thinking has to do with an (old) microsoft article I posted below. In debug builds, implicit initialization occurs in some cases using special values to help catch errors. This does not happen in release builds, only debug builds. This is my first time using linux dev tools and I thought there could be a chance something similar was happening.

Comment: @user987280 Yes, it *might* crash your program. Those zeroes can't be depended on, because C doesn't dictate how frames and calling conventions work. However, given certain implementations, it is possible that the 'uninitialized value' always ends up being zero. It's not as if that garbage value squatted that part of the stack (in case of static allocation) while it wasn't used. It could contain anything from the point of view of standardized C, but certainly not if you go beyond that (here: a single program compiled by single implementation on a single platform).

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't look like garbage values

Zero in this context **is** just a special case of "garbage value" (or more properly indeterminate value), that you can't rely on in any case, here is a slightly modified example, that produces different value on my compiler (`gcc 4.4.7`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and `gdb` session:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at check.c:6
6       for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x4004cc <main+8>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x0
(gdb) x/4xb $rbp-0xc
0x7fffffffe124: 0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
```

Good analogy for that might be random number generator, that returns zero. Zero is the same random value just as `112` or `377`.